# How to Refer to Specified Item in List Where Name is Reserved

Tags: list, applescript

I have a list (aList) of which item 1 is

```
{{issued:{|date-parts|:{{2000, 11}}}, |number|:"CMU/SEI-2000-TR-030", |id|:"noauthor_cmmi_2000", title:"CMMI SM for Systems Engineering/ Software Engineering/ Integrated Product and Process Development, Version 1.01 (CMMI-SE/SW/IPPD, V1.01). Staged Representation.", |citation-key|:"noauthor_cmmi_2000", language:"en", publisher:"Carnegie Mellon Software Engineering Institute", |type|:"report"}}
```

from which I want to retrieve the 'number' item. Other list items may not have a number item or a different number of items and hence I want to try and retrieve the value ("CMU/SEI-2000-TR-030") using the item's key - 'number' rather than the order position

i.e.

```
try
    set documentID to ". " & number of item 1 of aList
end try
```

which fails because `number` is a reserved term.

Is there a way to get around this to retrieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe character (|) that many of your variables are surrounded with, force the enclosed characters to be treated as a variable. As an item within 'aList', you use |number|, so continue to surround 'number' with pipes when you use it later.

```
set documentID to ". " & |number| of item 1 of alist
```

FWIW, this is discussed under [Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_lexical_conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH214-SW4) in the Language Guide (as vertical bar character in identifiers) and the practice is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks. The format of the JSON returned and the variable names is outside my choice / control - it’s a zotxt feature.

Comment: Well, at least there is a mechanism for dealing with it. Note that the | do not become part of the variable name, they just set the edges.